# Log Out or Restart

Tags: login, shutdown, restart, logout

If I install updates and get prompted to restart my computer, will it make a difference if I just logged out and then logged back in?

Comment: Yes, restart is obviously not the same as logout.

Answer (score 0):

Only logging out only restarts the parts which where been loaded for you the user) not the parts like the kernel and parts which where started for root.

So best advice is always do a reboot then instead of a logout/in.